# SQL adding multiple columns

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im trying to do a Top 10 but adding multiple columns together and grouping them by component between a certain date range, if i take the SUM's out it works like a charm, but when i put them back in i get the exception below, its been a while and i could just be having a brainfart.

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 10 ComponentName, (SUM(ISNULL(ulCompSizeFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulLeadCountFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulVPSHeightFailure,0))) as Total 
       FROM [i_import_slot_vision_errors] 
       WHERE DATE_TIME >= @startdata2 
           AND DATE_TIME < @enddata2 
       GROUP BY ComponentName 
       ORDER BY (SUM(ISNULL(ulCompSizeFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulLeadCountFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulVPSHeightFailure,0))) as Total DESC"
```

Problem is im getting an SQL exception, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Comment: ORDER BY items can't have "as". Simply do `ORDER BY Total DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct syntax, you can't alias an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT TOP 10 ComponentName, (SUM(ISNULL(ulCompSizeFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulLeadCountFailure,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(ulVPSHeightFailure,0))) as Total 
FROM [i_import_slot_vision_errors] 
WHERE DATE_TIME >= @startdata2 AND DATE_TIME < @enddata2 
GROUP BY ComponentName 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Don't forget, in SQL the `ORDER BY` clause is read by the computer after the `SELECT`, you can use the alias made in the `SELECT` in your `ORDER BY`.